# Passing "website’s security certificate" on react and electron

Tags: reactjs, certificate, electron

I have an application that was written in react and contained on electron framework.

In this application, I have to show a local machine(https) with unsecure option. I am able to open UI by using explorer bypassing warning

[Certificate error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFrLF.png)

However, I cannot open the UI in react app. Here my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Page from 'components/Page';

export default class EditorPage extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // this is needed, because InfiniteCalendar forces window scroll
    //window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
  render() {

    const uri = "https://IPv4:port" 

    return (
      <Page>
        <div>
       <webview src={uri} style={{height:700+'px'}}></webview>
       </div>
      </Page>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I pass the certificate problem?